# Creating a single viewmodel for separate entities in knockout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm, knockout.js

So,I have 2 C# entities in my application.i was planning on using the same knockout viewmodel to bind these 2 entities to the view.The model is as follows

```
public class Provider
{
    public int ProviderID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ProviderDetails ProviderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ProviderDetails
{
    public int ProviderDetailsId { get; set; }
    public string Certification { get; set; }
    public string Specialization { get; set; }
    public string TaxonomyCode { get; set; }
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following HTML

```
 <body>
  <div class="container">
       <h1 class="col-sm-offset-3">Enter Provider Details:</h1>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="providerDetailsForm" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the First Name" id="firstName" data-bind="value: firstName, @*hasFocus: setTheFocusaAfterReset*@ event: { keypress: allowOnlyAlphabets }" name="firstName" maxlength="20">
                <span class="col-sm-4 error"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">Last Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Last Name" id="lastName" name="lastName" data-bind="value: lastName, event: { keypress: allowOnlyAlphabets }" maxlength="20">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">Certification:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="certification" name="certification" data-bind="value: certification, options: certificationArray, optionsCaption: 'Select a Certification'">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">Specialization:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="specialization" name="specialization" data-bind="value: specialization, options: specializationArray, optionsCaption: 'Select a Specialization'">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">Taxonomy Code:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Taxonomy code" id="taxonomyCode" name="taxonomyCode" data-bind="textInput: taxonomyCode" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

The knockout bindings here were when the there was single entity Provider.I had to split the entities to show Parent-Child relationship between the tables in the DB.The relationship is one-one.
I was thinking of creating a single viewmodel like so.

```
var ProviderViewModel
{
      var self = this;
      self.providerID = ko.observable("");
      self.firstName = ko.observable("");
      self.lastName = ko.observable("");
     //This is where I am facing difficulty.How do I include the  Providerdetails within this viewmodel.
}
```

Now,I have the code for the Providerdetails separately like so

```
   self.specializationArray = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.certificationArray = ko.observableArray(["M.B.B.S", "M.D.", "R.N.", "M.S.N."]);
    self.certification = ko.observable("");
    self.specialization = ko.observable("");
```

But how do I include it in the same viewmodel.I ma little confused.Kindly guide me in the right direction.

The MVC controller code for the creation.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateProvider(Provider provider)
    {
        try
        {
            int providerCreationSuccessful = _repository.CreateProvider(provider);
            if (providerCreationSuccessful == 1)
                TempData["userIntimation"] = "Provider Registered Successfully";

            return RedirectToAction("ShowTheListOfProviders");
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(Ex.Message);
            return View("Error");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not making a property of each:

```
var ProviderViewModel = function(){
    //these 2 can be observable if needed
    this.provider = new Provider();
    this.details = new ProviderDetails();
};     
var Provider = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.providerID = ko.observable("");
    self.firstName = ko.observable("");
    self.lastName = ko.observable("");
};
var ProviderDetails = function(){
    self.specializationArray = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.certificationArray = ko.observableArray(["M.B.B.S", "M.D.", "R.N.", "M.S.N."]);
    self.certification = ko.observable("");
    self.specialization = ko.observable("");
};
```

Then in your HTML you can bind this way for `Provider`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Last Name" id="lastName" name="lastName" data-bind="value: provider.lastName, event: { keypress: allowOnlyAlphabets }" maxlength="20">
```

And using details member for `ProviderDetails`:

```
<select class="form-control" id="certification" name="certification" data-bind="value: details.certification, options: details.certificationArray, optionsCaption: 'Select a Certification'">
 </select>
```

Comment: I have to use the same view in my application.Its a demo project.The requirement is to have the same view for listing ,creating and editing the providers

Comment: Would my view bindings still remain the same?Also the controller action method for saving the provider to the database takes the Provider object as a parameter.Would the same method work,if I have separate  view models for the 2 entities.That is why I was thinking of having the providerdetails within Provider.Didn't know,how to do that?

Comment: @MichealS .. Thanks for taking the time out to answer my question.Would my controller method which is taking the Provider object as a parameter now change.

Comment: @AbhishekKS I believe it shouldn't change, just note you should pass the vm.provider now.

Comment: I am thinking it would not have the providerdetails if I pass the vm.provider to the controller,I am saving data into both the tables in the database.So,Would i not need both provider and providerdetails.One of the reasons I thought,I needed the same viewmodel for both provider and providerdetails

Comment: @AbhishekKS If you need both, simply pass the vm

Comment: I could pass the vm,but shouldn't the C# controller work with the C# entities.Hence I thought the vm should reflect the C# provder entity as in have the providerdetails within the provider.Then passing it to the controller would have been that much simpler.I could just ave the provider object as a parameter in the controller.

Comment: @AbhishekKS Are you using ASP.NET MVC as your backend? If so, please add this tag and info to your question. Try to be as clear as possible. Add the controller method code if you can. I'll try to look into it tomorrow.

Comment: Yes,I am using ASP.NET MVC 4.I will add the code now.Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for the misinforrmation.

Comment: @MichealS : I have been using the default form post to post the data to the controller.But now,with the separation of entities,I think I will have to use AJAX to post the form.I have tried it already.It seems my jquery validation does not seem to be happening.Could you please guide me on the same.Would appreciate it a lot.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your first view model as you did:

```
var ProviderViewModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.providerID = ko.observable("");
    self.firstName = ko.observable("");
    self.lastName = ko.observable("");
}
```

Then you initialize this view model:

```
var vm = new ProviderViewModel();
```

Then you use `vm` variable instead of `self` to apply the rest of your properties:

```
vm.specializationArray = ko.observableArray([]);
vm.certificationArray = ko.observableArray(["M.B.B.S", "M.D.", "R.N.", "M.S.N."]);
vm.certification = ko.observable("");
vm.specialization = ko.observable("");
```

And then you bind your model:

```
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Would the data bindings in the view then change as well.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken nothing needs to be changed in your view

Comment: The controller action method for saving data into the database is currently taking Provider object as a parameter.Wondering if that will change.

Comment: Depends on how it is actually implemented, just do the check and you'll see for yourself